# Browserify: Unexpected Token - Error on restructuring project

Tags: reactjs, browserify, babeljs

My project works correctly in the current directory structure. When I try and restructure my project, browserify fails and throws an error stating unexpected token even though there is no difference in the code.

Specifically I want to move my app.js (that contains all my react components) out of the public directory into the root directory

**Original directory structure:**

```
├── README.md
├── data
│   ├── prod-dump.js
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── css
│   │   └── main.css
│   ├── index.html
│   └── scripts
│       ├── app.js
│       ├── bundle.js
└── server.js
```

**Required directory structure:**

```
├── README.md
├── data
│   ├── prod-dump.js
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── css
│   │   └── main.css
│   ├── index.html
│   └── scripts
│       ├── bundle.js
├── app.js
└── server.js
```

The initial few lines of code in my app.js are as follows:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Grid = require('react-bootstrap').Grid;
var Row = require('react-bootstrap').Row;
var Col = require('react-bootstrap').Col;
var Table = require('react-bootstrap').Table;
var Button = require('react-bootstrap').Button;
var Collapse = require('react-bootstrap').Collapse;
var Tabs = require('react-bootstrap').Tabs;
var Tab = require('react-bootstrap').Tab;
var Well = require('react-bootstrap').Well;
var moment = require('moment');
//var DummyData = require('../../data/prod-dump'); <-- changed this line to the next one
var DummyDate = require('./data/prod-dump');



/* Header row for channels page */
var ChannelTableHeaderRow = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
     /* Loop through headers to generate each header jsx */
     var headers = this.props.headers.map(function(header) {
            return ( 
                <th>{header}</th>
            );
     });
    return (
        <tr>
            {headers}
        </tr>
     );
 }
```

});

Now when I run my browserify command, I get the following error log:

```
SyntaxError: /path/app.js: Unexpected token (21:20)
  19 |          var headers = this.props.headers.map(function(header) {
  20 |                 return (
> 21 |                     <th>{header}</th>
     |                     ^
  22 |                 );
  23 |          });
  24 |         return (
```

The command that I am running is:

```
browserify -t [babelify] ./app.js -o ./public/scripts/bundle.js
```

Comment: What's in your [`.babelrc` file](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/)? Alternatively, it looks like [babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify#cli) lets you pass in preset directly on the CLI.

Comment: Oh yes! I forgot to move the .babelrc file to the root directory. That solves the problem!!